# Gmail 421-4.7.0 Errors

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

Trying to post a question, but keeps getting flagged as spam.  Attaching an image of the question. Nothing like recursive problems.

[image: Snapshot of the question]

Comment: Not sure what might be happening if you are spam-flagged, but dumping an image containing a question is probably not the way to go forward.

Comment: I agree, but if I were to remove any more detail out of the question, it wouldn't be coherent.

Comment: Information needed to understand your question should be included within the text of the question, not as an image. Text in images isn't searchable, doesn't display well or use lots of data on some mobile devices, and are blocked by some companies.

Comment: Like I said, I tried to post the question as text, but it was flagged as spam. Not sure how else to post a question.